# Perform value validation with lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, iteration, google-chrome-devtools, selenium4

I need to perform validation that specific String is appearing in DevTools traffic (Selenium 4 / Java)
I saw several examples like this:

```
devTools.addListener(Network.responseReceived(), entry -> {
    System.out.println("Response (Req id) URL : (" + entry.getRequestId() + ") "
            + entry.getResponse().getUrl()
            + " (" + entry.getResponse().getStatus() + ")");
});
```

The code above works correctly, it prints out the traffic response value.
But I need not just to print the values but to perform validation if some specific String is contained in one of the entries response URL.
I tried something like this:

```
boolean responseFound = false;

devTools.addListener(Network.responseReceived(), entry -> {            
            if (entry.getResponse().getUrl().contains(expectedUrl)){
                responseFound = true;
            }            
});
```

However Java considered this as illegal since

> Variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final

So I changed it to be

```
AtomicBoolean responseFound = new AtomicBoolean(false);

devTools.addListener(Network.responseReceived(), entry -> {
            if (entry.getResponse().getUrl().contains(expectedUrl)){
               responseFound.set(true);
           }
});
```

However the code above doesn't work.
While debugging I see the flow never performs the `if` statement, it directly goes to the next line....
How can I make it working correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The listener is likely receiving events on another thread. I'm guessing you want to block the main thread whilst waiting for the response event. There's a few ways to do this, here's an example with a [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)

```java
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
List<Response> responses = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
AtomicBoolean urlFound = new AtomicBoolean(false);

devTools.addListener(Network.responseReceived(), entry -> {
   responses.add(entry.getResponse());
   if (response.getUrl().contains(expectedUrl)) {
      urlFound.set(true);
      latch.countDown(); // decrement the count
   }
});

latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // waits until count is zero for max of 10 seconds

if (urlFound.get()) {
   // yay we found it
} else {
   for (Response response : responses) {
      // report errors
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I followed after your code versions and really appreciate your efforts. However the current code catches only single, probably the first Response while network contains several Responses with different URLs while the required Response seems to be not the first. I can't know how many Responses will be caught here.

Comment: Also, I think the delay is not the problem. I can set some pause of 2-3 seconds or so. The main issue is to catch all the Responses and then iterate over them and validate their content.

Comment: In the listener you could check each event to find the one you are interested in. And only set the reference & countdown the latch once you've found the response you want

Comment: If you just want to wait 3 seconds and check all responses you could use `AtomicReference<List<Response>>`  and `Thread.sleep(...)` instead of a latch. Make sure to use a thread safe list (eg `CopyOnWriteArrayList`)

Comment: But I don't know how many responses are there. Also it can be that the required String is not there. So, I think we just need to put all the responses in some external List / Map etc and then to perform validation via the iterations. The original code that only prints the content works just perfect with no need for any kind of CountDownLatch

Comment: Another option is to use `new CountDownLatch(5)` and `AtomicReference<List<Response>>`. Then you could wait for the first 5 responses

Comment: I couldn't use `AtomicReference<List<Response>>` since I can't use index inside the lambda expression body... Is there any way to make just a normal iteration flow instead of this lambda expression?

Comment: I've updated my answer, you don't need `AtomicReference` if using a thread-safe `List`

Comment: When set `responseCount = 5` it didn't catch the required Response. Then tried to set count to 50. It still runs, more than 15 minutes... Is there some better way to make the things be done? Again, the initial code doesn't use any delay, prints all the responses in 2-3 seconds....

Comment: Just to iterate for each response initially caught by the listener. The listener is smart enough.

Comment: Again, I really very appreciate your help. But it still not working...

Comment: If you just want to wait for that specific URL. Just set the latch count 1 and only call `latch.countdown()` when you find the URL you want. Then the main thread would continue as soon as the first matching response is found

Comment: But how can I use `if` inside there? I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with lambda as you can see...

Comment: I've updated again

Comment: You are right! But I already found similar, but alternative way:  finally I'm checking the `latch.getCount() ==0` and if yes `responseFound = true;`. 
Thank you very, very much!